# Transfering a Set with a Wildcarded Generic to a List in Java

Tags: java, generics

I have a data type that contains a set and a method that expects `List<? extends MyClass>`.  The data type has `Set<? extends MyClass>`.  I need to be able to move the stuff out of the set and into the List.  The order it goes into the list doesn't matter, it just needs to start keeping track of it so that it can be reordered when displayed.  Suffice to say that changing the Set into a List in the data type is out of the question here.

This seems pretty easy at first.  Create a new method that takes a Set instead of a List, changes it into a list and then passes it on to the old method that just took a list.  The problem comes in changing the set to a list.

```
public void setData(Set<? extends MyClass> data) {
    List<? extends Myclass> newData = ArrayList< /* What goes here? */ >();
    for(ConcordaEntityBean o : data) {
        newData.add(o);
     }
     setData(newData);
}
```

Obviously, I can't instantiate an ArrayList with a wildcard, it chokes.  I don't know the type at that point.  Is there some way to pull the type out of data and pass it to ArrayList?  Can I just instantiate it with `MyClass`?  Is there some other way to do this?

Comment: Even if it'll ever work you'll get infinit recursion.

Comment: @Roman: how's that? `List` is not a subclass of `Set`, nor the other way around

Comment: @Roman There's another method with the signature: setData(List<? extends MyClass> data);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't instantiate it with `MyClass` because `newData` is not necessarily of type `List<MyClass>`, and Java does not support covariance (ie, `S` extends `T` does not imply that `ArrayList<S>` is a subtype of `ArrayList<T>`).

What you can do is this:

`List<MyClass> newData = new ArrayList<MyClass>();`

Now, everything in the `Set` (which is guaranteed to be a subtype of `MyClass`) can be put into `newData`.

Generally speaking, wildcard types enforce boundary constraints.  You know that `Set<? extends MyClass>` is a `Set` parameterized with *some type*, and that type is bounded from above by `MyClass`.  So when you are dealing with the elements from that `Set`, you can do no better than to treat them as `MyClass` objects.

Comment: The other option I found that worked, was to simply have the class in question take T as a class parameter.  Which for this instance - while it required more refactoring than I liked, worked.  This is better though.  Less refactoring.

Comment: A better reason not to do that is that (maybe) this method is not supposed to be parameterized.  It depends on whether you want `setData` to operate on all `Set`s, or only `Set`s of `MyClass` (and its subtypes).

Comment: Well, I could always parameterize the class to only take types that extend MyClass (T extends MyClass).

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
List<MyClass> newData = new ArrayList<MyClass>(data);
setData(newData);
```

?

Or even a one-liner:

```
setData(new ArrayList<MyClass>(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

I know my grasp of writing [generic methods](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html) is shaky, but it seems like this would work:

```
public <T extends MyClass> void setData(Set<T extends MyClass> data) {
    setData(new ArrayList<T>(data));
}
```

Comment: Close: public <T extends MyClass> setData(Set<T> data). But the setData that takes a list would also have to have the same kind of generics in the signature.